# Push, big file. Correct and improvement

Tags: perl

`dummy.pepmasses`

```
YCL049C                   1     511.2465  0 0 MFSK
YCL049C                   2    4422.3098  0 0 YLVTASSLFVA
YCL049C                   3    1131.5600  0 0 DFYQVSFVK
YCL049C                   4    1911.0213  0 0 SIAPAIVNSSVIFHDVSR
YCL049C                   5     774.4059  0 0 GVAMGNVK
YCL049C                   6     261.1437  0 0 SR
```

```
my $dummyfile = "dummy.pepmasses"; #filename defined here
my @mzco = ();

open (IFILE, $dummyfile) or die "unable to open file $dummyfile\n ";
while (my $line = $dummyfile){
    #read each line in file
    chomp $line;
    my $mz_value = (split/\s+/,$line)[3]; #pick column 3rd at every line 
    $mz_value = join "\n"; # add "\n" for data
    push (@mzco,$mz_value);  #add them all in one array @mzco
}
print "@mzco";
close IFILE;
```

There should be better way to express this one. How can it be ?
I want to pick up the third column and push it into an array. Are there better methods?

Comment: `$dummyfile` is your file name, not the lines in the file. The lines are read from the file handle `IFILE` like this: `my $line = <IFILE>`. Though it is better to use 3 argument open and a lexical filehandle: `open my $fh, "<", $dummyfile or die "Cannot open $dummyfile: $!";`

Comment: Curiously, your program can be reduced to a rather small one-liner: `perl -lanwe 'push @a, $F[3] END { print "@a" }' dummy.pepmasses`

Comment: @TLP Why would you collect an array in memory when you could simply write each value as soon as you read it?

Comment: @tripleee That is a good question. I just emulated the code functionality, but it is better written `perl -lanwe ' print $F[3] ' dummy.pepmasses`.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just go through your code and comment

```
open (IFILE, $dummyfile) or die "unable to open file $dummyfile\n ";
```

You should use 3-argument open with explicit mode, and a lexical file handle. Also, you should not include newline in the `die` message unless you want to suppress line number. You should also include the error, `$!`.

```
open my $fh, "<", $dummyfile or die "Unable to open $dummyfile: $!";

while (my $line = $dummyfile){
    #read each line in file
```

No, this just copies the file name. To read from the file handle, do this:

```
while (my $line = <IFILE>) {
```

Or `<$fh>` if you use a lexical file handle.

```
    chomp $line;
    my $mz_value = (split/\s+/,$line)[3]; #pick column 3rd at every line
```

This is actually the 4th column, since indexes start at zero `0`.

```
    $mz_value = join "\n"; # add "\n" for data
```

`join` does not work that way. It is `join EXPR, LIST` to join a list of values into a string. You want the concatenation operator `.`:

```
$mz_value = $mz_value . "\n";
```

Or more appropriately:

```
$mz_value .= "\n";
```

But why do it that way? It is simpler to just add the newline when you print.

```
print "@mzco";
```

You can do this:

```
print "$_\n" for @mzco;
```

Or if you are feeling daring:

```
use feature 'say';
say for @mzco;
```

And just to show you the power of Perl, this program can be reduced to a one-liner, using a lot of built-in features:

```
perl -lane ' print $F[3] ' dummy.pepmasses
```

- `-l` chomp lines, add newline (by default) to print
- `-n` put `while (<>)` loop around code: read input file or stdin
- `-a` autosplit each line into `@F`.

The program as a file would look like this:

```
$\ = $/;     # set output record separator to input record separator
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split;
    print $F[3];
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but if the OP wants the third column, it's `$F[2]`, yes? I saw your comment on the original code, but then you carried over the OP's mistake into your one-liner solution.

Comment: @MattJacob I assumed the mistake was on the other "side", that he meant fourth column. But yes, third column is `$F[2]`.